# Problem setting fieldId option for DataSet

Tags: typescript, vis.js, vis.js-network

I'm getting an error when trying to set the `fieldId` option for a DataSet I'm using with a Network graph. Without setting the `fieldId` option everything works great. Here's what I've tried:

```
import {DataSet} from "vis-data/peer/umd/vis-data";
import {Network} from "vis-network/peer/umd/vis-network";

...

const nodes = new DataSet(data.nodes, {fieldId: "uuid"});
const edges = new DataSet(data.edges);
const networkData = {nodes: nodes, edges: edges};
const network = new Network(container, networkData);
```

I get this Typescript error:

> Argument type {nodes: DataSet<PartItem, string>, edges:
> DataSet<PartItem<"id">, "id">} is not assignable to parameter type
> Data ...   Type DataSet<PartItem, string> is not assignable to
> type Node[] | DataInterfaceNodes | undefined     Type
> DataSet<PartItem, string> is not assignable to type Node[] |
> DataInterface<Node, "id"> | undefined       Type
> DataSet<PartItem, string> is not assignable to type
> DataInterface<Node, "id">

I understand that `id` is the default value of `fieldId`, but why can I not enter a new value (string) `uuid`, according to the documentation I am following? Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, unfortunately the packages are inconsistent in that respect. vis-network doesn't support changing the name of the id property.

To see this, in the vis-data package, `DataSet` allows a generic `Id_Prop` at lines 140-3 of the [code](https://github.com/visjs/vis-data/blob/dd27ea87ee49cb6b3f383be6e646b20df936da34/src/data-set.ts):

```
export class DataSet<
    Item extends PartItem<IdProp>,
    IdProp extends string = "id"
  >
```

but in the vis-network package that same generic parameter is set to `'id'` throughout (and in particular line 140 of the [typings file](https://github.com/visjs/vis-network/blob/db1669d64c481c8090634dd920dccba9cb013110/types/network/Network.d.ts)):

```
export type DataInterfaceNodes = DataInterface<Node, 'id'>
```

If you look directly at the [code](https://github.com/visjs/vis-network/blob/db1669d64c481c8090634dd920dccba9cb013110/lib/network/Network.js) of the `Network` class, it directly references an `id` property of nodes.

So it's intrinsic to how the packages are written.